# Hook execution failed: Failed to open TCP connection to ::1:8000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "::1" port 8000)

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-api, git-webhooks, python-gitlab

I need to integrate pivotal tracker manually because I want some extra options, but I'm getting a "failed to open TCP connection" error.
I'm working from localhost and gitlab is in an intranet. I've tried both the example in ruby in the docs and a similar script in python, but both give me the same error.
Would appreciate any help to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add the IP address to the HOSTS file.

Comment: Where is the HOSTS file?